# Rolling min/max in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

The database engine is SQLite3. It's a simple table:

CREATE TABLE T (ID INTEGER, DATE STRING, VALUE NUMERIC);

-- rows of T:

```
id date       value
1  2020-01-01 11
2  2020-01-01 23
3  2020-01-01 32
4  2020-01-01 41
5  2020-01-01 57
6  2020-01-01 62
```

How can I create a rolling min/max? Say of period 3:

```
id date       val   min3 max3
1  2020-01-01 11    11   11
2  2020-01-01 23    11   11
3  2020-01-01 32    11   32
4  2020-01-01 41    23   41
5  2020-01-01 57    32   57
5  2020-01-01 62    41   62
```

I keep getting min 11 Max 62 for everything because I don't know how to do the rolling min/max

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       min(val) over (order by date rows between 2 preceding and current row) min3,
       max(val) over (order by date rows between 2 preceding and current row) max3
from t;
```